# Is the run time complexity still O(n) when building a BST?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, binary-search-tree

What is the big-O (worst case) complexity of the total time required to build a binary search tree (BST) consisting of  nodes?

Hi, I understand that the run time complexity for worst case is O(n) for adding a single node to the tree. I would like to know if the run time complexity is still O(n) when building a BST.

Comment: `the run time complexity for worst case is O(n)` please be excruciatingly explicit: the *run time complexity* of ***what**, exactly*?

Comment: worst case scenario for binary tree is always O(n) since we know that not every bst search tree is balanced.

Comment: (Note that Muhteva explicitly stated the operation the claimed asymptotic run time limit shall apply to. You didn't in your question, you don't in [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68729595/is-the-run-time-complexity-still-on-when-building-a-bst?noredirect=1#comment121938628_68729595).

Answer (score 1):

It can be proven that a BST cannot be built in linear time regardless of the algorithm used to do it. At least, this proof will hold in the case that the values are ordered via comparison, and tricks such as "first sort the data using Counting Sort" are excluded. I think this is more useful than arguing from the angle of "you would have to call `insert` n times", which is just one way to construct a BST, and doesn't say anything about hypothetical alternative algorithms.

Applying the "you must call `insert` n times"-argument to different cases would show for example that binary heap cannot be built in linear time, and that a suffix tree cannot be built in linear time. But both of them *can* be built in linear time, using a different algorithm than "call `insert` n times". So it's a wrong argument in general, and we shouldn't use it here either.

If a BST could be constructed in linear time, then sorting is also possible in linear time:

1. build the BST in linear time,
2. then do an in-order traversal also in linear time, which yield the elements in sorted order.

Something about that must be false, because it is known that *comparison-based sorting* has a lower bound of needing at least Ω(n log n) comparisons. Doing the in-order traversal is possible, so it must be the other half of the this algorithm that is impossible. Hence it is impossible to build a BST in linear time (at least, it is impossible as long as the construction is based on comparisons).

Comment: `It can be proven that a BST cannot be built in linear time regardless of the algorithm used` Please do without a specification whether the input is ordered already.

Comment: @greybeard nice try but we both know that it is possible when the input is pre-sorted.